# Terraform flatten and looping issue inside modules

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a module in Terraform for creating Azure resources and facing some issues. This module creates a resource group, subnet, vnet and Role bindings. I see that the below code creates the resources twice because of the loop. Does the for_each loop work in such a way that the entire resource or module block will be executed each time it loops? I'm new to Terraform and come from a Java background.
Also, ideally would like to use the flatten inside the module without locals possibly, any way to do that? Code is below.

```
locals {
  groupsbyrole = flatten([
    for roleName, groupList in var.testproject1_role_assignments : [
      for groupName in groupList : {
        role_name  = roleName
        group_name = groupName
      }
    ]
  ])
}

module "testproject1" {
  source       = "C:\\Users\\ebo1h8h\\Documents\\Project\\Automation\\Terraform\\Code\\Azure\\modules\\sandbox-module"
  short_name = "testproj"
  # Resource Group Variables
  az_rg_location      = "eastus"
  az_tags = {
    Environment   = "Sandbox"
    CostCenter    = "Department"
    ResourceOwner = "Vikram"
    Project       = "testproj"
    Role          = "Resource Group"
  }
  address_space   = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  subnet_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  subnet_names    = ["a-npe-snet01-sbox"]
  vnet_location   = var.az_rg_location
  for_each = {
    for group in local.groupsbyrole : "${group.role_name}.${group.group_name}}" => group
  }
  principal_id         = each.value.group_name
  role_definition_name = each.value.role_name
}
```

And here is the role_assignments variable

```
variable "testproject1_role_assignments" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    "Contributor" = ["prod-azure-contrib-sbox", "gcp-org-network-engineering"],
    "Owner"       = ["gcp-org-cloud-delivery"]
  }
}
```

The above code creates 12 resources when it should be only 6. The only was I was able to get around this is have the resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" as a separate module. Ideally, I want to pass the role assignments variable in each of the module to be created so that it creates a set of resources.

Any pointers on how to achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: "The above code creates 12 resources when it should be only 6." - why do you expect 6? Your `local.groupsbyrole` would have only 3 elements, not 6 nor 12.

Comment: the module should create 1 resource group, 1 Vnet, 1 subnet, and 3 Role bindings in the resource group. Instead it loops and create everything twice.

Comment: Because you have `for_each`. So it executes multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) state

> If a resource or module block includes a for_each argument whose value is a map or a set of strings, Terraform will create one instance for each member of that map or set.

So in your scenario you are creating 3 instances of the module, whereas it sounds like you want to pass in the local.groupsbyrole object as a variable in the module and only attach the for_each to the resources you want multiple instances of.

Sidenote: You could simplify your local by adding group like below:

```
locals {
    groupsbyrole = flatten([
        for roleName, groupList in var.testproject1_role_assignments : [
            for groupName in groupList : {
                role_name  = roleName
                group_name = groupName
                group = "${roleName}.${groupName}"
            }
        ]
    ])
}
```

Tip: I find adding an output to see the shape of the object whilst developing can also be useful

```
output "test_output" {
    value = local.groupsbyrole
}
```

Then when you run plan you will see your object

```
test_output = [
  + {
      + group      = "Contributor.prod-azure-contrib-sbox"
      + group_name = "prod-azure-contrib-sbox"
      + role_name  = "Contributor"
    },
  + {
      + group      = "Contributor.gcp-org-network-engineering"
      + group_name = "gcp-org-network-engineering"
      + role_name  = "Contributor"
    },
  + {
      + group      = "Owner.gcp-org-cloud-delivery"
      + group_name = "gcp-org-cloud-delivery"
      + role_name  = "Owner"
    },
]
```

Comment: Yes, wanted to know if there is another way to achieve this without creating the resource twice. Even if we use the above method, it will create twice, once when it loops "Contributor" and when it loops "Owner". As I said, the way I worked around was creating a separate module for the role assignments, wanted to know if there was a better way? Another workaround was that I moved the logic of the local variables inside the child module instead of root module. But ideally want to do away with the locals and flatten inside the modules after assigning the value of testproject1_role_assignments.

Comment: The above would only create one instance of the module as I'm suggesting your second point, to handle the logic inside the child module by passing testproject1_role_assignments in to the module and move the local inside the child module.